# Antd input not displaying default object data name

Tags: next.js, antd

### The Problem:

So i have a searchable input that the user can use to lookup a `family` from the database, `antd` displays the selectable options and the search works, itll return the search results. however after selecting a value and associating it with the user, antd wont display the default result of the user, unless the result is already in the `selectableOptions` below. i've tried setting the data with `defaultValue` `value` etc. but to no avail, the only thing that seemingly works, is when i set the `name` attribute to `name={["family", "name"]}` this will indeed display the default name of the family i associate the user with but the form itself now takes out the entire object of the family where i need the `_id` field to make an association in the `api`

#### What I've tried:

As i've stated i've tried setting the default values, but that doesnt seem to work, if you console log the `form` the form is being set to the `object` thats coming from the server, but because the option doesnt exist in the form input, it doesnt show the value.

##### Code

Here is the setup for the `Select` Form

```
    <Form.Item
                  name={
                    // create the family object field
                    ["family"]
                  }
                  className={styles.inputParent}
                >
                  <Select
                    showSearch
                    placeholder="Select a family"
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    onSearch={(value) => onSearch(value)}
                    className={formStyles.input}
                    loading={familiesFetching}
                    options={familiesList?.families?.map((family: FamilyType) => ({
                      label: family.name,
                      value: family._id,
                      data: family,
       }))}
    />
</Form.Item>
```

The searching and everything works, i just cant figure out how to get it to associate the object thats coming from the database to the frontend input field. as i stated, if i change the `name` field, to something like `name={["family", "name"]}` this will work, the input will take on the `name` of the object, but i loose the object itself, and if i dont make any changes to that field i get an error because there isnt an `_id` on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out what it is i need to do in order for this to work correctly. What i needed to do was wrap the `Form.Input` in another `Input` and then set the field that searches the name equal to just the name. the top level feild holds the object id, and the second level field holds the name and displays it correctly.

so it looks like this:

```
<Form.Item name={["family"]}>
              <Form.Item
                name={
                  // create the family object field
                  ["family", "name"]
                }
                className={styles.inputParent}
              >
                <Select
                  showSearch
                  placeholder="Select a family"
                  optionFilterProp="children"
                  onSearch={(value) => onSearch(value)}
                  onChange={(value, option) => handleFamilyChange(value, option)}
                  className={formStyles.input}
                  loading={familiesFetching}
                >
                  {familiesList?.families?.map((family: FamilyType) => (
                    <Select.Option key={family._id} value={family._id} data={family}>
                      {family.name}
                    </Select.Option>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </Form.Item>
            </Form.Item>
```